# planets created from 1d perlin noise terrain look weird

Tags: python, pyglet, procedural-generation

i am trying to make planets using pyglet but they end up looking like stars [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YraKP.png)

here is my code
also i need a way to convert a batch to a sprite (to move it easily)

```
import pyglet
from pyglet import shapes
import opensimplex
import math
import time
brtd = 0
######## planets###########
class planetobj():
    def __init__(self,seed=1234,age=68,position=(0,0),color=(0,1,0),name="planet",description=" 127.0.0.1 , home sweet home  never will thy become infected with the virus that has a closedcure"):
     self.seed = seed
     self.age = age
     self.position = position
     self.color = color
     self.name = name
     self.description = description
    def gplanet(self,size):
     opensimplex.seed(self.seed)
     done = 0
     xc = 0
     c = 0
     self.terrain = []
     start = opensimplex.noise2(x=0, y=self.age)
     while (done == 0 or xc < 50) and not xc > 100 :
         xc = xc + 1
         c = c + size
         value = opensimplex.noise2(x=xc, y=self.age)
         self.terrain.append(value * size)
         if xc > 50:
          if math.floor(value * 100 ) == math.floor(start * 100):
             self.done = 1

    def mkplanet(self, x,y):
      self.batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch() 
      corner1 = (x,y)
      self.trias = []
      counter = 0
      cornerback = [0,0]
      for i in self.terrain:
            counter += 1
            radi = (360 / len(self.terrain)) * counter
            radi2 = (360 / len(self.terrain)) * ((counter + 1 ) % len(self.terrain))
            theta = self.terrain[(counter +1 ) % len(self.terrain)]
            corner3 = (x + math.sin(radi) * ( i )  ,math.cos(radi) * ( i ) + y )
            corner2 = (x + math.sin(radi2) * ( theta )  ,math.cos(radi2) * ( theta ) + y )
            self.trias.append(shapes.Triangle( x,y,corner2[0], corner2[1], corner3[0], corner3[1], color=(255, counter % 255, 255), batch=self.batch)     )
############ basic game logic  & rendering ###########
scr_X = 400
scr_Y = 300
window =  pyglet.window.Window(scr_X,scr_Y)
samplebatch = pyglet.graphics.Batch() 

earth = planetobj()
earth.gplanet(200)
planets = []
planets.append(earth)

earth.mkplanet( 50 ,50)
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    earth.batch.draw()
pyglet.app.run()
```

i tried changing the  values that get divided by 'len(self.terrain)'
but i could not find out how to make the planets look round

***EDIT***
thank you kind commenter (and also the rest of stackoverflow)

now i made a working version feel free to use it
'''

```
import opensimplex
import math
import pyglet
from pyglet import shapes
pi = 3.1459
debug = 0
class planetobj():
       def __init__(self,seed=1234,age=68,position=(0,0),color=(0,1,0),name="planet",description=" 127.0.0.1 , home sweet home  never will thy become infected with the virus that has a closedcure"):
        self.seed = seed
        self.age = age
        self.position = position
        self.color = color
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
    def gplanet(self,size):
     self.batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
     opensimplex.seed(self.seed)
     done = 0
     xc = 0
     c = 0
     self.terrain = []
     start = opensimplex.noise2(x=0, y=self.age)
     while (done == 0 or xc < 50) and not xc > 100 :
          xc = xc + 1
          c = c + size
          value = opensimplex.noise2(x=xc, y=self.age)
          self.terrain.append(value * 10 + size)
          if xc > 36:
              if math.floor(value * 100 ) == math.floor(start * 100):
                  self.done = 1

    def mkplanet(self, x,y):
        global debug
        corner1 = (x,y)
        self.trias = []
        deltatheta = 360 / len(self.terrain)
        for counter,i in enumerate(self.terrain):
            theta1 = ((deltatheta * counter)/180) * 3.1459
            theta2 = (deltatheta * (counter + 2)/180) * 3.1459
            radius = self.terrain[counter]
            print(str(theta1) + "," + str(theta2))
            radius2 = self.terrain[(counter + 1 )% len(self.terrain)]
            corner2 = (x + radius2 * math.cos(theta1), y + radius * math.sin(theta1))
            corner3 = ( (x + radius2 * math.cos(theta2)), (y + radius2 * math.sin(theta2)))
            self.trias.append(shapes.Triangle(x,y,corner2[0], corner2[1], corner3[0], corner3[1], color=(255, counter % 255, 255), batch=self.batch)     )
            if debug == 1:
             self.trias.append(shapes.Circle(  corner2[0], corner2[1], 2, color=(255, counter % 255, 40), batch=self.batch)     )
             self.trias.append(shapes.Circle(  corner3[0],  corner3[1], 2, color=(255,255, 255), batch=self.batch)     )
            

############ basic game logic  & rendering ###########
scr_X = 400
scr_Y = 300
window =  pyglet.window.Window(scr_X,scr_Y)
samplebatch = pyglet.graphics.Batch() 

earth = planetobj()
earth.gplanet(150)


earth.mkplanet( 250,150)
print(earth.batch)
earth.batch.draw
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    earth.batch.draw()
    print("drawing")
pyglet.app.run()
```

'''

Comment: Well, to make round things you would use `shapes.Circle`, not `shapes.Triangle`, right?

Comment: actually no ,  i am trying to use several small triangles to display the planet since triangles are often used in computer graphics  : https://www.quora.com/Why-does-graphics-hardware-only-render-triangles?share=1

Comment: That's true if you need color gradation, but I don't see you doing that.

Comment: '  for i in self.terrain:
            counter += 1
            radi = (360 / len(self.terrain)) * counter
            radi2 = (360 / len(self.terrain)) * ((counter + 1 ) % len(self.terrain))
            theta = self.terrain[(counter +1 ) % len(self.terrain)]
            corner3 = (x + math.sin(radi) * ( i )  ,math.cos(radi) * ( i ) + y )
            corner2 = (x + math.sin(radi2) * ( theta )  ,math.cos(radi2) * ( theta ) + y )
            self.trias.append(shapes.Triangle( x,y,corner2[0], corner2[1], corner3[0], corner3[1], color=(255, counter % 255, 255), batch=self.batch)     )'

Comment: this is the code that tries to do that  but the triangles do not seem to connect to each other?

Comment: Please don't include code in comments.  As you see, it doesn't work.  If you need to change the question, modify the question.

Comment: You have your terms messed up.  What you call `radi` and `radi2` are really your thetas -- those are the angles of the two sides of the triangle.  What you call `theta` is actually the amplitude -- the radius.  And your trig functions are not right -- x should be based on cos and y should be based on sin, but you're mixing angles and amplitudes.  Let me see if I can post a working version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've corrected your trigonometry, but there are some other issues.  The random values you get back from the noise generator are between -1 and 1.  You are then multiplying that by the planet size, which gives you wild variations from wedge to wedge.  What you want is to have a basic wedge size, which you use the noise to adjust bit by bit.  Here, I'm saying that the noise should be 3% of the wedge size (size/30).

I didn't want to download opensimplex, so I've used a uniform random number generator.  I'm also using matplotlib to plot the triangle, but see if this is closer to what you intended.

```
import math
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class planetobj():
    def __init__(self,seed=1234,age=68,position=(0,0),color=(0,1,0),name="planet",description=""):
        self.seed = seed
        self.age = age
        self.position = position
        self.color = color
        self.name = name
        self.description = description

    def gplanet(self,size):
        done = 0
        xc = 0
        self.terrain = []
        start = random.uniform(-1,1)
        while (done == 0 or xc < 50) and not xc > 100 :
            xc = xc + 1
            value = random.uniform(-1,1)
            self.terrain.append(size + value * size / 30)
            if xc > 50 and math.floor(value * 100) == math.floor(start * 100):
                done = 1

    def mkplanet(self, x,y):
        corner1 = (x,y)
        self.trias = []
        deltatheta = 360 / len(self.terrain)
        for counter,i in enumerate(self.terrain):
            theta1 = deltatheta * counter
            theta2 = deltatheta * (counter + 1)
            radius = self.terrain[counter] 
            corner2 = (x + radius * math.cos(theta1), y + radius * math.sin(theta1))
            corner3 = (x + radius * math.cos(theta2), y + radius * math.sin(theta2))
#            self.trias.append(shapes.Triangle( x, y, corner2[0], corner2[1], corner3[0], corner3[1], color=(255, counter % 255, 255), batch=self.batch)     )
            self.trias.append(( x, y, corner2[0], corner2[1], corner3[0], corner3[1], (1.0,(counter%255)/255,1.0) ))


earth = planetobj()
earth.gplanet(200)

earth.mkplanet(50 ,50)
print(earth.trias)
plt.figure()
plt.scatter( [48,48,52,52],[-50,50,-50,50] )
for t in earth.trias:
    tri = np.array(t[:6]).reshape(3,2)
    plt.gca().add_patch(plt.Polygon( tri, color=t[6] ))
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]